# How does integration of forms make sense?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, line-integrals

I don't understand how integration of a $k$-form on a manifold makes sense. For simplicity let's assume $M$ is a smooth $k$-manifold, $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow M$ is a smooth curve on $M$ and that $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$. Then by definition, $$\int_{\gamma} \omega = \int_{[a,b]} \gamma^* \omega$$ In coordinates $(x^i)$ we can write $\omega = \omega_i dx^i$ so that we then have $$\int_{[a,b]} \gamma^* \omega = \int_a^b (\omega_i \circ \gamma)d\gamma^i = \int_a^b (\omega_i \circ \gamma) \frac{d\gamma^i}{dt}dt$$

From an elementary calculus point of view, when integrating, we take the value of $(\omega_i \circ \gamma) \frac{d\gamma^i}{dt}$ at a point on some subrectangle of some partition, which gives us a real number. We then multiply it by the length of the subrectangle (which is approximated by $dt$), which is also a real number and we add these products up, then let the mesh of the partition tend to $0$.

From a differential forms point of view, $(\omega_i \circ \gamma) \frac{d\gamma^i}{dt}$ is a function that is being multiplied by the $1$-form $dt$. The value of $(\omega_i \circ \gamma) \frac{d\gamma^i}{dt}$ at a point of a subrectangle is a real number, but the value of $dt$, since it is a covector **field**, is a covector. Thus the value of $(\omega_i \circ \gamma) \frac{d\gamma^i}{dt} dt$ at a point of a subrectangle is a covector as well. How does it make sense to sum up a bunch of covectors to obtain a real number (the value of the integral)?

Comment: Well, you're integrating on $\mathbb{R}$, so there's a canonical way to identify covectors with numbers.

Comment: In any case, it seems silly to say that the "dt" of the elementary calculus Riemann sum has to be identified with the $dt$ that is a covector.  It's just notation.   But it's convenient notation since integrating a function on $[a,b]$ (in the elementary calculus sense) gives the same answer as integrating that function times the $1$-form $dt$ (in the integrals of forms sense).

Answer (score 1):

> How does it make sense to sum up a bunch of covectors to obtain a real number (the value of the integral)?

A differential n-form measures oriented n-volumes of supplied n vectors. Those measurements are real numbers and can be summed up.

Integration operator feeds $dx$ with (infinitesimal) tangent vectors at (continuum) consecutive points along a curve: $\int_C dx=\lim\sum dx_{p_i}(v_i)$.